# java virtual method that does not return void

Tags: java

I want a method in a derived class to override a virtual method in a CONCRETE base class AND return something (i.e. not void) like this:

```
public class HelloWorldApp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.go();
    } 
}

public class Foo
{
    public void go()
    {
        System.out.print(this.test().toString());
    }

    protected Integer test()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo
{
    @Override
    protected Integer test()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing this without the redundant 'return 1;' in Foo.test() which will never get run. It works fine obviously but it just seems like I'm doing something badly wrong.

Comment: How about making it abstract?

Comment: You can declare the test() method abstract if you're not intending to use the base interface

Comment: Are you going to have different subclasses returning things of different types from `test()`?  Or is it always either `Integer` or nothing?

Comment: @Dawood always the same type

Comment: @jontro, Foo is a class i don't control, it is an Activity in Android.

Comment: Then what's your question? What do you want to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot make `Foo.test()` abstract for some reason you didn't show in your example (for example because `Foo` extends a concrete class) and you are sure it will never be called, throwing a runtime exception may be preferable if there is no reasonable default value:

```
protected Integer test()
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Calling test on Foo is not supported");
}
```

There are examples for this in the Java core APIs, see for example [UnsupportedOperationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) - this one has a slightly different meaning though, it is used for optional methods that some implementations of certain collection-types implement and some don't.

Comment: Yes that is the reason I can't make it abstract, extending a concrete class. I guess I like this way better than returning something just to keep the compiler happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

*This answer was created **before** the question was updated to state that the base class must be concrete.*

---

If you expect `Foo`'s `test` method never to be run, then enforce it by making the `Foo` class `abstract`, with `test` being `abstract`.

```
public abstract class Foo {

    public void go() {
        System.out.print(this.test().toString());    
    }

    abstract protected Integer test();
}
```

Comment: Foo is a class i don't control, it is an Activity in Android.

Comment: I want to populate a type with different values depending of which sub Activity it is before posting it to web server

Comment: I edited question to make it clearer that the base class is concrete